# How to add newline return after regex search before and after the regex pattern?

Tags: macos, unix, sed, terminal

I have a text file containing some DNA sequences. It's on one line but I'd like to separate it in multiple lines.

```
>JH739887TTTACAATGTATAATAGAAACTAAAACTGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAATTTAAGAATCTTCAAAAATGTTTAAGTGGTGATAATCTCCCCAGTGTGAGAAACACACTTGGAAGGAAGTCACAAGTCAAATTTAGATTTGTTGCTTAATAATGGATTTGTAAGTATTATCAAATACTCAAGCACtaaggaaacaggaaaatctgaaatgttCACTTGCTTCTAAACATTTGCAGCCGAGTCCAACTTACACAGGGTAAGATGAGTTTTACAGACAGACACTATTTGTTATTAGGTCAGCTACAGTAAGTGAAAAAACTCACCTCTTTAAGTCTGATAAAGTAGCAGAAagtcatattttaaatatcagtaTAAACAAATGCTCTAAGTTTGGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAAGAACCTTCAAAAACATTTAAGTGCTGGTTATCTCCCCAGTGTGT>JH739882TTTACAATGTATAATAGAAACTAAAACTGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAATTTAAGAATCTTCAAAAATGTTTAAGTGGTGATAATCTCCCCAGTGTGAGAAACACACTTGGAAGGAAGTCACAAGTCAAATTTAGATTTGTTGCTTAATAATGGATTTGTAAGTATTATCAAATACTCAAGCACtaaggaaacaggaaaatctgaaatgttCACTTGCTTCTAAACATTTGCAGCCGAGTCCAACTTACACAGGGTAAGATGAGTTTTACAGACAGACACTATTTGTTATTAGGTCAGCTACAGTAAGTGAAAAAACTCACCTCTTTAAGTCTGATAAAGTAGCAGAAagtcatattttaaatatcagtaTAAACAAATGCTCTAAGTTTGGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAAGAACCTTCAAAAACATTTAAGTGCTGGTTATCTCCCCAGTGTGT
```

I'm able to look at the place where I want to separate the file:

```
grep '>[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}' ~/Desktop/text2.txt
```

The Regex ">[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}" looks for the pattern `">JH######`.

But whenever I use the sed command to add a line return before and after the regex search, it doesn't work:

```
sed  '/>[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}/a/b\ 
\n' ~/Desktop/text2.txt
```

This is the error I have:

```
sed: 1: "/>[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}/ ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

This command below is running, but not giving the expected result:

```
sed  '/>[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}/a\ 
\n' ~/Desktop/text2.txt
```

This is the result I'm expecting (the first line should not have a return before it, but for the rest of the matches they should have a line return before and after, the line return `¬` are included here for clarity):

```
>JH739887¬
TTTACAATGTATAATAGAAACTAAAACTGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAATTTAAGAATCTTCAAAAATGTTTAAGTGGTGATAATCTCCCCAGTGTGAGAAACACACTTGGAAGGAAGTCACAAGTCAAATTTAGATTTGTTGCTTAATAATGGATTTGTAAGTATTATCAAATACTCAAGCACtaaggaaacaggaaaatctgaaatgttCACTTGCTTCTAAACATTTGCAGCCGAGTCCAACTTACACAGGGTAAGATGAGTTTTACAGACAGACACTATTTGTTATTAGGTCAGCTACAGTAAGTGAAAAAACTCACCTCTTTAAGTCTGATAAAGTAGCAGAAagtcatattttaaatatcagtaTAAACAAATGCTCTAAGTTTGGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAAGAACCTTCAAAAACATTTAAGTGCTGGTTATCTCCCCAGTGTGT¬
>JH739882¬
TTTACAATGTATAATAGAAACTAAAACTGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAATTTAAGAATCTTCAAAAATGTTTAAGTGGTGATAATCTCCCCAGTGTGAGAAACACACTTGGAAGGAAGTCACAAGTCAAATTTAGATTTGTTGCTTAATAATGGATTTGTAAGTATTATCAAATACTCAAGCACtaaggaaacaggaaaatctgaaatgttCACTTGCTTCTAAACATTTGCAGCCGAGTCCAACTTACACAGGGTAAGATGAGTTTTACAGACAGACACTATTTGTTATTAGGTCAGCTACAGTAAGTGAAAAAACTCACCTCTTTAAGTCTGATAAAGTAGCAGAAagtcatattttaaatatcagtaTAAACAAATGCTCTAAGTTTGGAAATGTTAATCTTGAAAGAACCTTCAAAAACATTTAAGTGCTGGTTATCTCCCCAGTGTGT¬
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed  's/>[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}/\n&\n/g;s/^\n//' file
```

- `s/>[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}/\n&\n/g`: add a newline character before and after every matching string
- `s/^\n//`: remove newline character added in the first line

Comment: It's printing something, but it doesn't add the line return: `n>JH739887nTTTA`. This is the result I got for the first few characters

Comment: You're on a Mac?

Comment: Yes, how does that make a difference? Is it only for Linux?

Comment: A real quick around is to install gnu-sed and use `gsed` (brew install gnu-sed) https://superuser.com/questions/307165/newlines-in-sed-on-mac-os-x. Worked with this...

Comment: A `\n` character in the substitution string is not POSIX compliant and it won't work with FreeBSD sed. But there is a workaround, using ANSI-C style escape: `sed  's/>[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}/\'$'\n&\'$'\n/g;s/^\'$'\n//'`. Another way is to install GNU sed as you did...

Answer (score 0):

I hate sed but it's a fun challenge:

```
sed -nE '
  :loop
      s/./&/
      tcontinue
      bnext

  :continue
      h
      s/(^>[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}).*/\1/
      p

      g
      s/^>[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}//

      h
      s/>[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}.*//
      p

      g
      s/[^>]+//
      tloop
  :next
' file
```

It's **such** a fun challenge, understanding this program is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep, you could write

```
grep -oP '>[A-Z]{2}\d{6}|(?<=>.{8})[^>]+' file
```

But you probably don't have GNU grep on your Mac. Try plain perl

```
perl -pe 'chomp; s/(>[A-Z]{2}\d{6})([^>]+)/$1\n$2\n/g' file
```